# Add TailwindCSS to SinatraRB

Tags: tailwind-css, sinatra

What is the easiest way nowadays to add [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) 3.4 to a [Sinatra](https://sinatrarb.com/) 4 app?
Is there a way to avoid `npm` and all the `JS` complexity that comes with that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid installing Tailwind CSS via the Node.js ecosystem, i.e. `npm`, you can download and use the [standalone binary](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli) which is described as a:

> […] [standalone CLI build](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/releases/latest) that gives you the full power of Tailwind CLI in a self-contained executable — no Node.js or npm required.

Comment: that could be a good option. Thanks for pointing it out.